# Oracle to SQLServer export

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration

I have to move data from existing database oracle to which I don't have direct access. The data is about 11 tables, 5GB each. The database admin can export the tables to some .csv or xml. The problem with csv is that some data is textual with lots of special characters. The problem with xml is that the markup is an overhead which will increase significantly the size of the files. The DBA admin is not competent enough to provide a working and neat solution. He uses toad as the database tool. Can you provide some ideas how to perform such a migration in the best possible way?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new DBA

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below steps to migrate the data from Oracle to SQL server.

Recommended Migration Process
To successfully migrate objects and data from Oracle databases to SQL Server, Azure SQL DB, or Azure SQL Data Warehouse, use the following process:

1.Create a new SSMA project.

2.After you create the project, you can set project conversion, migration, and type mapping options. For information about project settings, see Setting Project Options (OracleToSQL). For information about how to customize data type mappings, see Mapping Oracle and SQL Server Data Types (OracleToSQL).

3.Connect to the Oracle database server.

4.Connect to an instance of SQL Server.

5.Map Oracle database schemas to SQL Server database schemas.

6.Optionally, Create assessment reports to assess database objects for conversion and estimate the conversion time.

7.Convert Oracle database schemas into SQL Server schemas.

8.Load the converted database objects into SQL Server.

You can do this in one of the following ways:

```
 * Save a script and run it in SQL Server.

 * Synchronize the database objects.
```

9. Migrate data to SQL Server.

10.If necessary, update database applications.

For more details : 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017]

Comment: Yes, but... as I wrote: "...to which I don't have direct access", I can't do "Connect to the Oracle database server."

Answer (score 0):

After the admin export data into CSV, try to convert it into a character set which will recognize all special characters.
Then, try to follow the steps from this link: [link](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx), it might work.
If after the import, there are still special characters, thy to manually convert them.

Answer (score 0):

Get the DBA to export the tables using the ASCII delimiters which were designed for this purpose:

```
Row delimiter: Decimal 30 / 0x1E
Column delimiter: Decimal 31 / 0x1F
```

Then you can use BCP (or any other similar product) to upload the data to SQL Server.